# Total number of leaves binary tree with n internal nodes

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, trees, catalan-numbers

Using the definition of a leaf as being an internal node with no children (both children are external nodes), how can I find the total number of leaves for all binary trees with n internal nodes, for any n.

I know the number of binary trees with n internal nodes is given by Catalan numbers however I can't work out how to enumerate all $C_n$ trees for each n to find number of leaves (as defined above).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Using the definition of a leaf as being an internal node with no children" This doesn't make sense. A **leaf** has no children and internal node is typically called a branch and has children.

Comment: @N8tron I  took that from Sedgewick and Flajolet, regardless in this case I'm considering a leaf an internal node with both children external nodes

Comment: Okay now that I've caught onto your notation. I'm going to share a link that can help that make more sense to people using the standard definitions. Note though that even S & F use the standard definition in their appendix ;)  http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf

Comment: @N8tron thanks, I should've made it more clear I was not looking at the standard definition

Comment: Do you want to consider isomorphism classes of rooted trees or any tree? or do you want to consider isomorphism classes at all?

Comment: @N8tron I am considering a binary tree as either an external node or an internal node connected to an ordered pair of
binary trees. Of size n=3, the following trees would be counted. [3  internal nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Catalan_number_binary_tree_example.png) These have 6 total 'leaves' as defined above.

Comment: Given all $C_n$ binary trees with $n$ internal vertices you should be able to produce all $C_{n+1}$ binary trees with $n+1$ internal vertices by taking a binary tree with $n$ internal nodes and adjoining two external nodes to it converting an external node to an internal node with no internal children. There will be collisions the first example happens when $n=3$ but you can fairly easily identify these since they will be stabilized by a non-trivial graph automorphism.  You could also use orbits under branch permutations to generate quite a few.